# Python: convert string [('a',0.2),('b',0.9),('a',0.4)] to dataframe

Tags: python, string

In Python, how to convert a string like

```
thisStr = '[('a', 0.332), ('d', 0.43766), ('b', 0.3244), ('b', 0.76577), ('a', 0.863), ('d', 0.96789)]'
```

into a DataFrame something like

```
index   item     value
0       a        0.332
1       d        0.43766
2       b        0.3244
3       b        0.76577
4       a        0.863
5       d        0.96789
```

Comment: It's a list of tuples...

Comment: Your text a b d, does it define elsewhere as another string var or it should be 'a' 'b' and 'd', eg. ('a', 0.332)?

Comment: thanks for comments, ive made an update to make it more clear what im trying to do

Comment: Item b having 2 value as 0.3244 and 0.76577, do you need to access them individually ? When access item b, what you expect it to get ?

Comment: the value of 'b' is a probability, so there is many trails of 'b' and each one gives a probability, so for example I might average all the values of 'b'

Comment: item column is not an index column

Comment: Maybe show us a simple example how you wanna use or access the DataFrame

Comment: example: like delete all rows where 'a' is less than 0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to change the string into a pandas dataframe and then do some manipulations. I'd change the string to the following through some simple replaces and manual editing on the beginning and end of the string. You're escaping the punctuation except for the ends so that you can apply the eval() function.

```
import pandas as pd

thisStr = eval('[(\'a\', 0.332), (\'d\', 0.43766), (\'b\', 0.3244), (\'b\', 0.76577), (\'a\', 0.863), (\'d\', 0.96789)]')

df = pd.DataFrame(thisStr)
df.rename(columns={0:'item', 1:'value'}, inplace=True)

# one approach to solving the problem of removing rows where
# item a has values less than 0.8.
mask = (df['item'] == 'a') & (df['value'] < 0.8)
df2 = df[~mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using eval function turn the string into list of tuples

```
# change to double quote " because contains single quote within string
thisStr = "[('a', 0.332), ('d', 0.43766), ('b', 0.3244), ('b', 0.76577), ('a', 0.863), ('d', 0.96789)]"

# this turn the string into list of tuples
mylist = eval(thisStr)
# mylist[0][0] access 1st row item which is 'a'
# mylist[0][1] access 1st row value which is 0.332

# to remove all row 'a' less than 0.8
newlist = [i for i in mylist if not (i[0]=='a' and i[1] < 0.8)]
```